# Swift--Reading in JSON file

Tags: ios, json, swift

Using Xcode 6.4 and programming in swift.

I am typing a program that should read in JSON from a URL. A sample of the JSON can be found at this URL (https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topmovies/limit=2/json) and Ive been using this site to parse the JSON in order to read it better (http://json.parser.online.fr/).

Now I need to work through the levels of the JSON in order to get to
the actual movie names and image URL's but I am lost at what kind of variable entryDictionary should be. I was thinking it should be an array of dictionaries, and this compiles, but the output of entryDictionary in the console is sloppy looking, starting with Optionl( and not entry{  as it should. And when I go to loop through entryDictionary, I get an error saying entry does not have a subscript of type AnyObject.

So I am asking how I retrieve the im:name fields and im:image from the JSON.

```
func downloadDataFromURLString(urlString: String) {

   //Downloaded data and is now stored in data. Took code out because 
   //irrelevant to my problem at this point. Data variable has correct
   //JSON, now I am trying to parse it.

            } else { //download suceeded, time to parse
                var error: NSError? = nil
                var names = [String]()

                if let rootDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &error) as? [String: AnyObject] {

                    let feedDictionary = rootDictionary["feed"] as! [String: AnyObject]

                    let entryDictionary: AnyObject? = feedDictionary["entry"]

                    println(entryDictionary) //For debugging

                    //for entry in entryDictionary as! NSArray {
                      //  let name = entryDictionary["name"]
                       // let image = entryDictionary["image"]
                       // let movie = Movie(name: name!, image: image!)
                       // weakSelf!.movies.append(movie)
                    //}
```

here is a blueprint of the JSON

```
"feed":{
    "author":{},
    "entry":[
    {
        "im:name":{
          "label":"Deadpool"
         },
        "im:image":[],
        "summary":{},
        "im:price":{},
        "im:contentType":{},
        "rights":{},
        "title":{},
        "link":[],
        "id":{},
        "im:artist":{},
        "category":{},
        "im:releaseDate":{}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AnyObject is indeed not subscriptable (you're trying to subscript a variable whose type is AnyObject? with `["feed"]`). You should also avoid casting to Cocoa container types like NSArray and NSDictionary whenever you can. Here's an example of how you might get the labels out of the entries array's names array:

```
import Foundation

func labels(feedDictionary:[String:AnyObject]) -> [String] {
    guard let entries = feedDictionary["entry"] as? [String:AnyObject] else {
        return []
    }

    return entries.flatMap { (key:String, value:AnyObject) -> String? in
        guard key == "im:name" else {
            return nil
        }

        guard let name = value as? [String:String] else {
            return nil
        }

        return name["label"]
    }
}
```

I'd however advise against using NSJSONSerialization on its own in Swift for anything but the simplest case, as you end up casting and wrapping optionals until the cows come home.

There are good 3rd party libraries such as [Freddy](https://github.com/bignerdranch/Freddy) and [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) which apply Swift language features to accomplish a very convenient JSON (de)serialization experience.

For instance with Freddy you could express your problem in the following style:

```
let json = try JSON(data: data)
json.decode("feed", type:Feed.self)

struct Feed: JSONDecodable {
    let entries:[Entry]
    init(json: JSON) throws {
        self.entries = try json.arrayOf("entry", type:Entry.self)
    }
}

struct Entry:JSONDecodable {
    let name:IMName
    init(json: JSON) throws {
        self.name = try json.decode("im:name", type:IMName.self)
    }
}

struct IMName:JSONDecodable {
    let label:String
    init(json: JSON) throws {
        self.label = try json.string("label")
    }
}
```

Comment: JAL, that's fair. Just typing up a full solution using Freddy as an example, one moment.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am actually going to double check to ensure that using third party libraries is allowed, as this is an assignment for school. Is it going to be next to impossible and sloppy code to parse without a third party library? I believe this sort of coding problem will be on my final in a few weeks and we wont have 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Oh, totally not impossible of course, but in a "real" commercial setting for instance tedious, repetitive and rather bug prone.

Comment: Ok, added at least some hints in my answer to how you may solve your problem without 3rd party dependencies.

Comment: Thanks you. I will use the Freddy if my professor emails me and confirms this is allowed. But the answer without Freddy will help me while studying for the test